# How to export flink user custom metric to prometheus & grafana

Tags: java, apache-flink, metrics

I'm trying to create my custom metric variable according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vesj-ghLimA)

With the sample code it's provided, I can get the events and the Histogram.

I'm confused how the identifier been used by prometheus & grafana. I also trying to modify the sample code little bit but the metric just no longer work.

Also, I'm only able to access the system metric but not my own.

My question is:

1. how can I access the counter I created? for example counter1
2. What is the metricGroup exactly?
3. For example, I'd like to detect a pattern
   from an input stream, and it's more reasonable to do it in the
   metric or just output the result to a timeseries database like
   influxdb?

thanks in advance.

Here is the map function

```java
class FlinkMetricsExposingMapFunction extends RichMapFunction<SensorReading, SensorReading> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private transient Counter eventCounter;
  private transient Counter customCounter1;
  private transient Counter customCounter2;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    eventCounter = getRuntimeContext()
        .getMetricGroup().counter("events");

    customCounter1 = getRuntimeContext()
        .getMetricGroup()
        .addGroup("customCounterKey", "mod2")
        .counter("counter1");
    customCounter2 = getRuntimeContext()
        .getMetricGroup()
        .addGroup("customCounterKey", "mod5")
        .counter("counter2");

 //    meter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().meter("eventMeter", new DropwizardMeterWrapper(dropwizardMeter));
  }

  @Override
  public SensorReading map(SensorReading value) {
    eventCounter.inc();
    if (value.getCurrTimestamp() % 2 == 0)
      customCounter1.inc();

    if (value.getCurrTimestamp() % 5 == 0)
      customCounter2.inc();

    if (value.getCurrTimestamp() % 2 == 0 && value.getCurrTimestamp() % 5 == 0)
      customCounter1.dec();
    return value;
  }
}
```

Example Job:

```java
env
.addSource(new SimpleSensorReadingGenerator())
.name(SimpleSensorReadingGenerator.class.getSimpleName())
.map(new FlinkMetricsExposingMapFunction())
.name(FlinkMetricsExposingMapFunction.class.getSimpleName())
.print()
.name(DataStreamSink.class.getSimpleName());
```

---

## Update

Screenshot for access flink metrics from grafana:

[image]

flink-config.yaml

```
FROM flink:1.9.0
RUN echo "metrics.reporters: prom" >> "$FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml"; \
    echo "metrics.latency.interval: 1000" >> "$FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml"; \
    echo "metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter" >> "$FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml"; \
    mv $FLINK_HOME/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-*.jar $FLINK_HOME/lib
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/build/libs/*.jar $FLINK_HOME/lib/
```

default map function from tutorial:

```java
 @Override
 public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    eventCounter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().counter("events");
    valueHistogram = getRuntimeContext()
            .getMetricGroup()
            .histogram("value_histogram", new DescriptiveStatisticsHistogram(10_000_000));
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The counter you created is accessible by `<system-scope>. customCounterKey.mod2.counter1`. `<system-scope>` is defined in your flink-conf.yaml. If you did not defined it there the default is `<host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index>`.
2. A metric group bascially defines a hierarchy of metric names. According to the documentation the metric-group is a named container for metrics. It consist of 3 parts (scopes): The system-scope (defined in flink-conf.yaml), a user scope(whatever you define in `addGroup()`) and a metric name.
3. That depends on what you want to measure. For everything which you could detected for counters, gauges or meters I would go for the metrics. If it comes to histograms you should have a closer look on what you get from flink if you use the prometheus reporter. Flink generalizes all different metric frameworks - the way histogramms are implemented in prometheus is different than in e.g. graphite. The definition of buckets is given by flink and can't be changed as far as I know (despite some relection magic).

All this is described in more detail here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#registering-metrics

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thansk a lot, it's very clear. Just one more question, in the above flink-prometheus-grafana example, I can't found the counter I define in flink from grafana. Do I need to modify something to access it from grafana? Thanks

Comment: Can you find flink's own metrics in grafana? So is the repoter configured in the right way?

Comment: I just upload more details in above. I can find flink's own metrics but not my own or even the metrics it's define in that tutorial. By default, the tutorial is using docker to run flink and flink-config.yaml was created during the docker build. Do I need to export <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index> in config?

Comment: The tutorial example is using the getMetricsGroup() method. Is that will automatically map <events>(the counter in map function) to <flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_events>(flink build-in metrics)?

Comment: @TobiSH, In <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index>., where do we get tm_id, operator_name, subtask_index? job_name is in prometheus.yaml, I understand.

Comment: My problem is that I can see default metrics on prometheus dashboard(prometheus has its own basic dashboard), but  no custom metrics of mine.

Comment: @Machinedoll Is this problem resolved!! I am facing exact same issue where I can see all flink's default system metrics to prometheus but not the one which I created. I have also not defined any scope in flink-conf.yaml file. Can you please share how did you overcome this issue.. Thanks in advance..